# CORS xmlhttprequest HEAD method

Tags: methods, xmlhttprequest, head, cors

When requesting header data using HEAD method with CORS object, it returns null.

getAllResponseHeaders() -> return null.

How to setup php headers in the other site so that I can retrieve header data>

p.s.: this is not within the same domain. it's a cross origin resource sharing

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed this behavior in Firefox (3.6.13); getAllResponseHeaders() returns nothing.  In Chrome/Safari, getAllResponseHeaders() only returns simple response headers (as defined in the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#terminology).  None of these browsers respect the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.

Answer (score 1):

Since the last answer to this question, modern browsers respect the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.

This bug is fixed in up to date versions of IE (11) and Chrome (43) and Firefox (39).