# How can I get response header via cross-domain ajax?

Tags: ajax, http-headers, cross-domain, cors

I'm trying to read documentation and I must confess it is not an easy reading. I have no problem (after adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header) to read responseText, but fail to get response header anywhere except Firefox.

So, my question is what is the right way to get response header, using cross-domain ajax?

I've tried to use ([Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#Access-Control-Expose-Header)), but, again, failed to read header.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So the way it should work is that you specify the headers you want the client to have access to in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.  For example, if your server sets a Foo response header, and you want the client to be able to read it, your server should also send the following header:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Foo
```

On the client side, you can read all the response headers by calling xhr.getAllResponseHeaders().  This returns the response headers as a string, which you can then parse into an object using the following code: https://gist.github.com/706839

That is an explanation of how things *should* work.  However, note that there is a bug in older browsers where the response headers can't be read on the client.  See here for more details: [CORS xmlhttprequest HEAD method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561221/cors-xmlhttprequest-head-method/4863887#486388)

Comment: Hi, I have added the following to server-side API. `header(Access-Control-Allow-Headers: temp');` `header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: temp);` `header('temp: '. 12345);` When I am making a cURL request to the API, I get the headers along with the response-data. But when I am making an AJAX call to the same API, I only get the data, without the header.

Comment: Anish, your comment sounds more appropriate as its own Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Is this question / answer relevant even today.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, and found answer on Chromium mailing list that this is fixed in webkit, and it will be implemented in crhomium ~19.

I will try to find topic and update my answer.