# Response header is present in browser but not parsed by Angular $http response.headers()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-headers, httpresponse

In our Angular app, we need to parse response headers of some $http.

In particular we need to parse some X-prefixed response headers, for example `X-Total-Results: 35`.

Opening the `Network` tab of the browser dev tools and inspecting the resource relative to the $http request, I verified that the response header `X-Total-Results: 35` is present.

in the browser, the X-Total-Results header is available, but cannot be parsed in the Angular $http.

Is there a way to access in $http the 'raw' response and write our custom parser for the header?

```
$http.({method: 'GET', url: apiUrl,)
    .then( function(response){
        console.log('headers: ', response.headers());
        console.log('results header: ', response.headers('X-Total-Results'));
        // ...
    })
```

**console output**

```
headers: Object {cache-control: "no-cache="set-cookie"", content-type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"}

results header: null
```

Comment: That's very weird, do you have any interceptors that might be modifying the returned promise?

Comment: no, I do not have any interceptor

Comment: @yvesmancera I also thought it weired! if the header is visible in the dev tool browser it means it should be accessible in angular, right? Or there might still be some problem with CORS or similar issues? The api is accessed cross domain and I have CORS on it I will update the question with the other headers.

Comment: Now that you mention CORS, this is most definitely your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112524/how-can-i-get-response-header-via-cross-domain-ajax

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. Right now I have `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Total-Results` and of course `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

Comment: @yvesmancera YESSSSSS `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` did the trick!

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help! Mind if I post it as an answer?

Comment: @yvesmancera do you know if wildcard can be used, something like `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Total-*`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reason you can't read the header on JavaScript but you can view it on the developer console is because for CORS requests, you need to allow the client to read the header.

Your server needs to send this header:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-Total-Results
```

To answer your question in the comments, The `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` does not allow wildcards according to the [W3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header)

Comment: This solves the problem. Thats interesting though, I thought that the developer console is a client....  Just by guessing I would have expected to be analogous to the angular/javascript client running in the same browser... clearly I am missing something.

Comment: You can also view HTTPOnly cookies on the developer tools while you can't read them on JavaScript.

Comment: saved my day, i had a Cors-Toggle chrome plugin, only few headers i was able to see because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Use  $httpProvider.interceptors you can intercept both the request as well as the response

for example

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$injector', function ($q, $injector) {
             return {
                 'responseError': function (response) {
                     console.log(response.config);
                 },
                 'response': function (response) {
                     console.log(response.config);
                 },
                 'request': function (response) {
                     console.log(response.config);
                 },
             };
         }]);
```

**Update : You can retrive your headers info in call itself**

```
$http.({method: 'GET', url: apiUrl)
    .then( (data, status, headers, config){
        console.log('headers: ', config.headers);
        console.log('results header: ', config.headers('X-Total-Results'));
        // ...
    })
```

Comment: the response object is available in the $http callback: `$http().then(function(response){ // response object available here })` the problem is it does not parse the results header I am interested in -- see question.

Comment: your update code is buggy, did you mean .success(function(data, status, header, config) {}) ?